# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@orderwhere'

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax

Why is the following syntax generates the error "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near '@orderwhere'"

```
use orders
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
set @orderwhere = 'order_status.step = 1'
select order_status.order_id
from order_status
where @orderwhere
```

Comment: You want to use dynamic SQL. Then you have to `exec()` it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have parts of your query being dynamic. It has to be all or nothing. Then use [EXEC()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx) to run your dynamic query

```
exec('select order_status.order_id
      from order_status
      where ' + @orderwhere)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your where clause is a string. You should use dynamic SQL or something like this:

```
use orders
declare @orderwhere varchar(5000)
set @orderwhere = '1'
select order_status.order_id
from order_status
where order_status.step = @orderwhere
```